# facebookSDK, Swift3 and AppDelegate to handle logins

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Following the [docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login)

I've implemented the login button fine, the app passes off to the fblogin completes fine, however after i log in i get passed back to the app and the console always reads

"User cancelled Login"

Some searching around the web shows that i need to add something to AppDelegate.Swift however the docs only have code for Objective-C projects.

there is [this guy's guide](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/) however i think it's written for swift 1.x

altering it slightly catered for the dropping of NSURL i'm using:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     sourceApplication: String?,
                     annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

But i am getting the error 'application(*:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)' has been renamed to 'application(*:open:sourceApplication:annotation:)'

Anyone have any ideas how to get this delegation to work and getting the right stuff back from a Facebook login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make changes in appdelegate as below :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

with FacebookCore.ApplicationDelegate (that I hope it will be named FBApplicationDelegate) as it follow

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return FacebookCore.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey] ?? [])
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FacebookCore.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

refer link for more : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/35

Comment: Absolute legend, i owe you a beer.